# Kotlin / What i need to pass to init: (index: Int)->Contact?

Tags: kotlin

I have a question, what value I need to pass to `"init: (index: Int)->Contact"` as it expects:

> The integer literal does not conform to the expected type (Int) ->
> TypeVariable(T)

**Snippet of the function**

```
   @Composable
    fun ContactList(textVal: MutableState<TextFieldValue>, navigateToProfile: (Contact) -> Unit) {

    var contacts = remember { DataProvider.contactList }
    var contactList = contacts.toMutableList()
    var filteredContacts: MutableList<Contact>
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
    ) {
        val searchText = textVal.value.text
        filteredContacts = if (searchText.isEmpty()){
            contactList
        }
        else{
            val resultList = MutableList<Contact>(10, "init: (inded: Int)->Contact")
            for (contact in contactList) {
                if (contact.contains(searchText.lowercase())) {
                    resultList.add(contact)
                }
            }
            resultList
        }
        items(filteredContacts) {
            ContactListItem(contact = it, navigateToProfile)
        }
    }
}
```

**Snippet of the Contact**

```
data class Contact(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val description: String,
    val recipe: String,
    val ImageId: Int = 0
)
```

Comment: What do you really want to achieve with your code?

Comment: I want to filter the list, so I could get the result of my searchText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(index: Int)->Contact` means: a function that receives `Int` and returns `Contact`. But I guess this does not really solve your problem.

The problem is that you use `MutableList` "constructor" (it is actually a function) which is intended to create a list with exactly `10` items. Then you need to provide these items and this is what `init` function is for. What you actually need here is to create an empty list and you can do this with:

```kotlin
val resultList = mutableListOf<Contact>()
```

However, if you just need to filter some collection and create another one, it is much easier to use [filter()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html):

```kotlin
val resultList = contactList.filter { it.contains(searchText.lowercase()) }
```

If `Contact.contains()` is an `operator` then we can also simplify it to:

```kotlin
val resultList = contactList.filter { searchText.lowercase() in it }
```

Comment: A slightly simpler form of that is `…filter{ searchText.lowercase() in it }`.

Comment: Yes, I decided to keep the code similar to the original one to not add confusion. Also because we don't know whether `contains()` is `operator`. But I guess it makes sense to at least mention it. Thanks. @gidds